# NodeJS Express Async issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this function which gets some data from my database but i'm having a trouble calling the function and getting the proper response

```
  function getEvents()
  {
    var x = [];
    var l = dbCollection['e'].find({}).forEach(function(y) {
    x.push(y);
  });

 return x;
});
```

and another function which calls this function but it always returns undefined.
How can i make the function wait till mongoose has finished filling up the array?

Thanks for the help! [My life](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL0qe.png)

Comment: You need to use a callback strategy for returning and some promise management to solve the mongoose issue.

Comment: @JJ9 if your question is answered please mark answer as accepted for not keepin it open

Answer (score 0):

`dbCollection['e'].find` is called non-blocking way so you are returning `x` before filling. You need to use callbacks or some mongoose promises. You can get all returning values from database like following snippet

```
function getEvents(callback) {
    dbCollection['e'].find({}, function(error, results) {
        // results is array.
        // if you need to filter results you can do it here
        return callback(error, results); 
    })
}
```

Whenever you need to call `getEvents` function you need to pass a callback to it.

```
getEvents(function(error, results) {
    console.log(results); // you have results here
})
```

You should read mongoose [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) for how queries work.

There is also support for promises in mongoose. You can check [this url](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) for more information about promises.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by @orhankutlu should work fine.

I will give another solution using promise. You can choose one between these two solutions depending on your style of programming.

Solution using promise:

```
function getEvents() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        dbCollection['e'].find({}, function(error, results) {
           if (error) return reject(error);

           var x = [];
           results.forEach(function(y){
              x.push(y);
           });
           // forEach() is a blocking call, 
           // so the promise will be resolved only 
           // after the forEach completes
           return resolve(x); 
        });
    });
};
```

Calling getEvents():

```
getEvents().then(function(result){
    console.log(result);   //should print 'x'
}).catch(function(err){
    // Handle error here in case the promise is rejected
});
```

I will encourage you to try both the approaches, ie, using callbacks and using promises. Hope you find it useful!